# how to replace html block of codes with another block of codes with inline css in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to replace block of html codes replace with another block of html. but i could not do it.

this is the html block

```
<div id="book1">
    <div class="page1" style="background: url(modules/mod_test/tmpl/img/new/1.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
    <div class="page2" style="background: url(modules/mod_test/tmpl/img/new/2.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
    <div class="page3" style="background: url(modules/mod_test/tmpl/img/new/3.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
    <div class="page4" style="background: url(modules/mod_test/tmpl/img/new/4.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
</div>
```

with this code block

```
<div id="book2">
    <div class="page1" style="background: url(modules/mod_test/tmpl/img/new/new1.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
    <div class="page2" style="background: url(modules/mod_test/tmpl/img/new/new2.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
    <div class="page3" style="background: url(modules/mod_test/tmpl/img/new/new3.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
    <div class="page4" style="background: url(modules/mod_test/tmpl/img/new/new4.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
</div>
```

i tried this with this code but it not working

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.test-img').click(function () {
        var lookbook2 = '<div class="page1" style="background: url(../images/book2/new1.jpg); width:100%;"></div>' + '<div class="page1" style="background: url(../images/book2/new2.jpg); width:100%;"></div>';
        $('#book1').append(lookbook2);
    });
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: are yo trying to replace just the contents or the whole div?

Comment: `.append()` means to add. If you want to replace something. You can use `$target.html('')`

Comment: as i can see content in both nodes same, the only difference is id of parent node, so -  `$('#book1').prop('id', 'book2')`

Comment: @lee_gladding content of the book1 div

Comment: @Evgeniy Check the url (the final file).. It's different between the blocks.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.test-img').click(function() {
        //save book2 html content
        var lookbook2 = $('#book2').html();

        //replace book2 html content with book1 html content
        $('#book2').html($('#book1').html());

        //replace book1 html content with the saved book2 html content
        $('#book1').html(lookbook2);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code I assume that you want to replace the div #book1 with div #book2 **on click of an element with class test-img**

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.test-img').click(function() {                           
        var lookbook2 = '<div id="book2"><div class="page1" style="background: url(modules/mod_test/tmpl/img/new/new1.jpg); width:100%;"></div><div class="page2" style="background: url(modules/mod_test/tmpl/img/new/new2.jpg); width:100%;"></div><div class="page3" style="background: url(modules/mod_test/tmpl/img/new/new3.jpg); width:100%;"></div><div class="page4" style="background: url(modules/mod_test/tmpl/img/new/new4.jpg); width:100%;"></div></div>';
        $('#book1').after(lookbook2);
        $('#book1').remove();
    });
}
```

Comment: @anuruddhika It should work.. try changing the height and width of the divs (in html and the lookbook2) to some pixels - and make sure you are clicking some element which has the class="test-img"

Answer (score -1):

To replace the whole block use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.test-img').click(function() {                           
        var lookbook2 = '<div id="book2"><div class="page1" style="background: url(../images/book2/new1.jpg); width:100%;"></div>'+'<div class="page1" style="background: url(../images/book2/new2.jpg); width:100%;"></div></div>';
        $('#book1').replaceWith(lookbook2);
    });
});
```

To just replace the content (keeping the div and ID the same) use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.test-img').click(function() {                           
        var lookbook2 = '<div class="page1" style="background: url(../images/book2/new1.jpg); width:100%;"></div>'+'<div class="page1" style="background: url(../images/book2/new2.jpg); width:100%;"></div>';
        $('#book1').html(lookbook2);
    });
});
```

example of replace content: http://jsfiddle.net/c5zzuymn/1/

EDIT: with images http://jsfiddle.net/c5zzuymn/2/

Comment: yeah seems to work fine... look at the quick example I just added.

Comment: well JS fiddle does not have your locally defined image paths ;) but I have updated with images. Still works. Might want to check your image paths for the new images? Check console in chrome or other similar dev tools?